# SQL linked server query error on PHP

Tags: php, sql-server, linked-server

I have a MSSQL query using a linked server. The query works great of MSSMS.

But I can't make it work on PHP.

```
SELECT 
l.USER_KEY as id, 
l.USER_ID as username, 
CASE WHEN l.PASSWORD = 'x' THEN 'blaze' WHEN l.PASSWORD = 'b' THEN 'xtreme' END AS server, 
CASE WHEN l.CHECKLOGIN = 0 THEN 'offline' WHEN l.CHECKLOGIN = 1 THEN 'online' WHEN l.CHECKLOGIN = 2 THEN 'banned' END AS status,
l.LOGINIP AS ip_address,
CASE WHEN l.PASSWORD = 'x' THEN g.CHARID0 WHEN l.PASSWORD = 'b' THEN xg.CHARID0 END AS slot1,
CASE WHEN l.PASSWORD = 'x' THEN g.CHARID1 WHEN l.PASSWORD = 'b' THEN xg.CHARID1 END AS slot2,
CASE WHEN l.PASSWORD = 'x' THEN g.CHARID2 WHEN l.PASSWORD = 'b' THEN xg.CHARID2 END AS slot3,
Convert(varchar, LOGINTIME,111) AS last_login
FROM game.dbo.CHAR_INFOR AS g
    JOIN login.dbo.USER_CHECK_LOGIN AS l 
    ON g.USER_KEY = l.USER_KEY
    JOIN XTREME.game.dbo.CHAR_INFOR AS xg --this is a linked server
    ON xg.USER_KEY = l.USER_KEY
    WHERE PASSWORD LIKE 'sbhacker0%'
ORDER BY last_login
```

This query when on PHP returns: (THE ERROR)

```
 Heterogeneous queries require the ANSI_NULLS and ANSI_WARNINGS options to be set for the connection. This ensures consistent query semantics. Enable these options and then reissue your query. (severity 16) 
 General SQL Server error: Check messages from the SQL Server (severity 16)
 Query failed
```

This is my script in PHP please review.

```
$con = mssql_connect('host\INST','user','pass') 
    or die('Could not connect to the server!');

// Select a database:
mssql_select_db('login') 
    or die('Could not select a database.');

// Example query: (TOP 10 equal LIMIT 0,10 in MySQL)
$SQL = "SELECT 
l.USER_KEY as id, 
l.USER_ID as username, 
CASE WHEN l.PASSWORD = 'x' THEN 'blaze' WHEN l.PASSWORD = 'b' THEN 'xtreme' END AS server, 
CASE WHEN l.CHECKLOGIN = 0 THEN 'offline' WHEN l.CHECKLOGIN = 1 THEN 'online' WHEN l.CHECKLOGIN = 2 THEN 'banned' END AS status,
l.LOGINIP AS ip_address,
CASE WHEN l.PASSWORD = 'x' THEN g.CHARID0 WHEN l.PASSWORD = 'b' THEN xg.CHARID0 END AS slot1,
CASE WHEN l.PASSWORD = 'x' THEN g.CHARID1 WHEN l.PASSWORD = 'b' THEN xg.CHARID1 END AS slot2,
CASE WHEN l.PASSWORD = 'x' THEN g.CHARID2 WHEN l.PASSWORD = 'b' THEN xg.CHARID2 END AS slot3,
Convert(varchar, LOGINTIME,111) AS last_login
FROM game.dbo.CHAR_INFOR AS g
    JOIN login.dbo.USER_CHECK_LOGIN AS l 
    ON g.USER_KEY = l.USER_KEY
    JOIN XTREME.game.dbo.CHAR_INFOR AS xg
    ON xg.USER_KEY = l.USER_KEY
    WHERE PASSWORD LIKE 'sbhacker0%'
ORDER BY last_login";

// Execute query:
$result = mssql_query($SQL)
```

Please advice, Thank you.

Comment: As was stated in the question I linked on your other question, you need to execute `mssql_query("SET ANSI_NULLS ON"); mssql_query("SET ANSI_WARNINGS ON");`